# how to validate form in email in AngularJS ?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-validation

I'm sending email using NodeJS with html/angularjs template.
There is a form, i'm sending in email. AngularJS validations are not working in email. How would I do validation?

Comment: What exactly is not working, can you show some relevant code?

Comment: @PankajRaut please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work also you can format your code with the button that looks like `{}` in the editor or highlight and press ctrl+k

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).